# what is the URL equivalent of an absolute path in non-windows system?

Tags: java, xml, url, birt

I am getting following exception while running BIRT from a Linux OS.

Caused by: org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException: no protocol: /home/lsingh/reporting/tmp/execution1279514184559/TDReport.xml

where "/home/lsingh/reporting/tmp/execution1279514184559/TDReport.xml" is my XML data file.

When i looked into the code of "org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.xml.util.XMLDataInputStreamCreator" class in the BIRT, I saw that the exeception is coming from following piece of code.

```
catch (MalformedURLException e)
{
  throw new OdaException(e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

It  means the code is trying to convert file path specified above into a URL and it fails.

So my question is how a non-windows path is converted into a URL?
should it be prefixed with file:/// ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows or not, all URLs to local files start with `file://`. That's the protocol prefix.

So your file would be:

`file://` + `/home/lsingh/reporting/tmp/execution1279514184559/TDReport.xml` = `file:///home/lsingh/reporting/tmp/execution1279514184559/TDReport.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the file URL:

```
file:///home/lsingh/reporting/tmp/execution1279514184559/TDReport.xml
```

If you can post the code than invokes BIRT, it will be easier to analyse the problem.